# How can I show ithat a language is regular?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language, formal-grammar

I have a very quick question about regular languages, I think $\{a^{2n}| n\geq 1\}$ is regular. I do know that pumping lemma can be used to show something that is not regular. I am wondering what should I use in order to show that $\{a^{2n}| n\geq 1\}$ is regular.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: I'd suggest you to also add a tag for regular languages :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show that a language, $L$, is regular with one of those:

- Express the language with a regex
- Make an NFA that recognizes $L$
- Make a DFA that recognizes $L$
- Determine a primitive recursive function $f:\Sigma^*\to\{0,1\}$with the property
  $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1\text{, if } x\in L \\0\text{, else}\end{cases}$$
  where $\Sigma$ is the alphabet of the language.